# Book to prepare for the exams CILS or CELI

Tags: word-meaning, meaning, sentences

Which books do you recommend to prepare for the exams CELI (or CILS) ?

I would like to train for the C1 level. I see that this reference book seems to be expired : https://www.guerra-edizioni.com/books/index.cfm?node=0,1,22,1006,168,1175.

What would you recommend ? Alternatively, strong online resources.

I tend to favor CELI because there is preparation and exam center in my city / country. Would you recommend otherwise ? What is the most challenging, the most recognized exam ?

Answer (score 1):

Here two books

1. [Facciamo il CELI4!](https://www.hoeplieditore.it/italiano-stranieri/articolo/facciamo-il-celi-4-marida-muscolino/9788820391430/1614)
2. [Celi 4 Test di preparazione (livello C1)](https://www.ornimieditions.com/it/catalogo2/certificati-linguistici/certificazione-celi/celi-4-test-di-preparazione-cd-audio-29-detail)